# Firefox - single word search

Tags: firefox, search

Within Firefox (17.0), if I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search for the word "time",  I only want the search to find "time", not other words that contain "time".  For example "datetime".  If I add a single or double quote to the word, it won't provide any results.  Is there a way to get around this, i.e., to search only for the exact text in the Find field?

Comment: Note: using these suggested "add a space" methods have a flaw -- like searching for " time ", it won't find "time. " or "time, " or "time" at the beginning of a line, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should search with a space before the word and search " time", instead of "time"...

Answer (score 0):

You should add space before and after the word 'time' like this: "`time`" (without the quote)
Now you'll be able to find exactly the word "time". Space after the word is important so it won't highlight the word something like "timetable"(if it exists).